# Setting HeaderRow to 1 results in no table displayed for itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

If I add the line `_table.HeaderRow = 1;` to my code the table is not in the PDF document.  But if I remove it the table is there.  I need the table headers to repeat on each page but I can't get the table to display when I try.

```
protected void StartTableWithOptions(float width, float leadSpacing, params float[] sizes)
{

    _table = new PdfTable(sizes.Length) { SpacingBefore = leadSpacing, KeepTogether = true, SplitRows = true, SplitLate = true};

    _table.HeaderRow = 1;

    if (width > 0)
    {
        _table.TotalWidth = width;
    }
    else
    {
       _table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    }

    _table.SetWidths(sizes);
    _table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    _table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
    _table.DefaultCell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0xAF, 0xAF, 0xAF);

}
```

Comment: You're not adding any content to the table anywhere, and you're not adding the table to a Document anywhere. Please provide a more substantial code snippet. Better yet: provide a small standalone example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Found the problem.  Using a generic package that is building the table.  Deeper in the table when it starts a new row it creates a new table so each row is actually a table.